# add text to file string using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm a bit of a newbie to batch files so please bear with me.

I have a text file that is formatted like an ini file. It contains lines of text like this:

```
Example1=123
Example2=
Example3=AAA

Example1=456
Example2=T001
Example3=BBB
```

How can I edit all occurences of Example2= to read Example2=NUL but ignore Example2 if there is anything after the equals symbol?

Comment: can you post an example of what you're tried? You could use FOR /F (pay attention to "tokens" and "delims" then redirect the output to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not strictly an answer per se as it is not a batch file solution but it is what I had to do to solve my issue. After hours of research and under time constraints I turned to Powershell. The code below is an example of what worked for me:

```
$IniFile = "D:\test\test.ini"
$Change = Get-Content $IniFile 
$Change | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "^example=$", "example=NUL"} | Set- Content $IniFile
```

The bit of regex in the -Replace parameter solved the issue.

Many thanks for taking the time to look.